# Blazor w/Syncfusion - Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'sfBlazor.methodCall' ('methodCall' was undefined)

Tags: blazor, syncfusion, syncfusion-blazor

Attempting to use the PDF Viewer (server) and keep getting the above error in the browser console.  It was working up until today and there is not a lot of code that goes with it.  Has anyone encountered this before?

```
<SfPdfViewerServer @ref="pdfViewer" ToolbarSettings="@ToolbarSettings" EnableFormFields="false" DocumentPath="@DocumentPath" EnableNavigationToolbar="false" EnableAnnotationToolbar="false" EnableToolbar="true" Height="100%" Width="100%">
     <PdfViewerCustomStampSettings EnableCustomStamp="true" IsAddToMenu="true" Width="194" Height="75" MaxHeight="75" MaxWidth="194" MinHeight="75" MinWidth="194" CustomStamps="@CustomStamps"></PdfViewerCustomStampSettings>
     <PdfViewerContextMenuSettings EnableContextMenu="false" />
     <PdfViewerAnnotationSettings IsLock="false" />
     <PdfViewerEvents AnnotationAdded="@AnnotationAdded" DocumentLoaded="@DocumentLoaded" AnnotationRemoved="@AnnotationRemoved" AnnotationSelected="@AnnotationSelected" />
</SfPdfViewerServer>
```

The above code is the simple code to load the viewer.  The following code is what loads the document.

```
byte[] byteArray = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(new Uri(docpath));
DocumentPath = "data:application/pdf;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site needed to be running in https.  Once I altered it to run secure it began working.